# Decoding ascii in url php

Tags: php, ascii, decode

I try to use ascii letters in my url-site but I don't know what i use ascii letters ( è , é , à, ect.. ) in my url. I try to use urlencode\urldecode but i can't view my page when i use a ascii letters. I don't know what resolve this problem.
Can you help me with an example pls ?

```
function my_url($offer) {
$dd = url_title($offer->number." ".$offer->number,"-",true);
return site_url("siteweb\view".$offer->number."/".urlencode($dd));
```

My problem is in "urlencode($dd)"

update

```
    function my_url($offer) {
$dd = url_title($offer->number." ".$offer->number,"-",true);
$ddd= rawurldecode($ddd)
return site_url("siteweb\view".$offer->number."/".htmlspecialchars($ddd));
```

Comment: I think you meant non-ascii characters...

Comment: Where are you trying to use the URL. If you are using the URL in URL context e.g. link, then it is correct that `olè` encodes to `ol%E3%A9`. However, if you display the URL to the user than is should be [`rawurldecode-ed`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) and then passed through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before displaying.

Comment: I try it , but i don't see anymore my url  :S
I use first urldecode and then htmentities

Comment: I use first htmlspecialchars or rawurldecode ?

Comment: rawurldecode first and then htmlspecialchars, but this should only be done if you intent to display it as readable text!

Comment: I don't see url , so.. only siteweb\view".$offer->number."/"

Comment: Could you [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55345720/edit) the question with what you have tried?

Comment: I do it! can you help me?

Comment: You can try use base64_encode / base64_decode to manage the url string, and urlencode at the end point.

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` when you `echo` it out, not when you prepare the URL.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

"htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities"

Comment: How does that help in the context of URL?

Comment: You should use htmlentities in url's too.. goto the link I posted and look at example #2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Clearly you did not read the manual then, straight from example #2:
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';

Comment: But in this way i can't use ( example: -olè) in my url 'cause it became :  mysite.it/ol%E3%A9  

I want use -olè

Comment: You need to decode it afterwards before trying to display it.

Comment: mmm.. how can i do ?

Comment: ok, now I am intrigued, why does the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) suggest to use both?

Comment: @PhantomMoore https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @Dharman its because they do different things in the same way, html encode escapes them but leaves them understandable to html, while url encode takes it escapes it and makes it understandable to url's. It depends on your use case really.

Comment: I get that, it is just I have never seen them both used together, or in any combination. I cannot think of any reason to use both of them. As you said `htmlentities` has a different purpose than `urlencode`

Comment: And for this case where he's trying to print the data back htmlentities works better. However you can use them together in unique cases. There's a good article on here somewhere, when I find it i'll link back to it.

Comment: [URL/HTML Escaping/Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783070/1839439) - Also check the comment under the second answer.

Comment: If i use htmlentities i don't see anymore my url >.>